# Is it possible to push from Qt to a server that has git installed

Tags: git, qt

I am trying to push my C++ project from Qt Creator to my server, but I can't find any direct solution.

I can only push from Qt to github. Then I pull the files from github, when connected to the server.

Is there any way that I can push directly from Qt to the server?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, you can push from Qt Creator to **any** git origin/remote. If you install git on your server and configure it to be available via `https`, you certainly can push to your own server! From git's perspective, your server is no different than github's. It's just a different URL.